# HDInsight Intellij Plugin Authentication

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, azure-hdinsight

I'm running the IntelliJ Community 2016.2.4 on OSX El Capitan and I'm trying to use the HDInsight Plugin to run a Spark Application on my Spark Cluster in Azure.

However, I run into an issue where when I try to authenticate the HDInsight plugin with my Azure subscription, it repeatedly asks me to sign in after a successful sign-in.

Any help around this or a point in the right direction would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience. Can you download and install the Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ? We have merged the HDInsight plugin to Azure Toolkit. The new version in Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ should solve the auth problem. Feel free to send me emails at xiaoyzhu at Microsoft dot com if you still see the issue in the integrated version.